# Unable to get the min_score search criteria working in ElasticSearch 0.90.0

Tags: elasticsearch

We've been having some trouble getting min_score to work.

We have two types. There is user_meta, the parent index type. There is also the child index, user_perk (specified below.)

The query returns both the right documents and accurate scores for those documents, but when I add a min_score >= 1, it returns no data.

Another weird behavior is that changing the boost value in constant_score does not change the score that is returned. For example, if I have a boost value of 1 and a document that has a score of 29, that document will also have a score of 29 if I set a boost value of 0.1.

Very confused here. Are we doing something wrong?

Thanks!
Jieren

**Mapping for child document**

```
{
    "user_perk": {
        "_parent" : {"type" : "user_meta"},
        "type": "object",
        "index_analyzer": "keyword",
        "search_analyzer": "keyword",
        "properties": {
            "quest_id": {"type": "string"},
            "ks_uid": {"type": "string"},
            "status": {"type": "string"},
            "action_dt" : {"type": "date", "format": "YYYYMMdd"}
        }
    }
}
```

**Query**

```
{
  "min_score": 5,
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "user_perk",
      "score_type": "sum",
      "query": {
        "constant_score": {
          "boost": 1,
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "status": "claimed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are all the scores of the document > min_score ?

Answer (score 0):

min_score is not >= 1, but > 1.
Put min_score: 0 and it should work.